# How to convert sql query with IN, NOT IN, UNION using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to convert a sub-query with NOT IN, IN and UNION operator to join? I need this query using joins no sub-queries so spring jpa can understand that

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM CONTACT 
  WHERE partner_idpartner = (
     SELECT partner_idpartner 
     FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL WHERE idBusinessChannel in (
       select idbusinessFrom from business WHERE idbusiness = 5943
     )
   )  
   and idcontact not in (
     SELECT CONTACT_IDCONTACT FROM businesscontact 
     WHERE BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS=5943
   )   
  UNION
  SELECT *  
  FROM CONTACT 
  WHERE partner_idpartner = (
    SELECT partner_idpartner 
    FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL WHERE idBusinessChannel in (
      select idbusinessTo FROM business WHERE idbusiness = 5943
    )
  )  
   and idcontact not in (
    SELECT CONTACT_IDCONTACT FROM businesscontact 
    WHERE BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS=5943
  )
```

Comment: Which subquery, you have two levels of sub-queries?

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson   i don't think i understand what you asking, you don't see sub-queries?

Comment: Yes of course I do but you have sub queries within sub-queries so is your question referring to all sub-queries or only the innermost or ...?

Comment: Yes,  we are migrating to framework that doesn't support sub-quries, so I need to flatten this ugly query completely

Comment: Does your "new framework" support CTEs (Common Table Expressions)?

Comment: @The Impaler yes it does, but i am avoiding using it, because i need to support multiple data sources

Comment: @Joakim Danielson there are  not one selects idbusinessFrom and second idbusinessTo

Comment: I think this is a good question whose answer is probably "don't do it". I'll upvote the question since it's of use to other people.

Comment: On a side note: `WHERE partner_idpartner = (...)` looks dubious to me, as the subquery seems to return multiple rows, so it should rather be `WHERE partner_idpartner IN (...)`. The whole query could easily be simplified by the way by using `EXISTS` in order to look up `idbusinessFrom` and `idbusinessFrom` in one step. We could thus get rid of half the query and it would probably run faster, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT CONTACT.*
FROM      CONTACT
JOIN      BUSINESSCHANNEL
ON        CONTACT.partner_idpartner = BUSINESSCHANNEL.partner_idpartner
JOIN      business
ON        (BUSINESSCHANNEL.idBusinessChannel = business.idbusinessFrom
AND       business.idbusiness = 5943)
OR        (BUSINESSCHANNEL.idBusinessChannel = business.idbusinessTo)
AND       business.idbusinessroute = 5943)
LEFT JOIN businesscontact
ON        CONTACT.idcontact = businesscontact.CONTACT_IDCONTACT 
AND       BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS = 5943
WHERE     businesscontact.CONTACT_IDCONTACT IS NULL
```

Comment: Though I think this query could get you the results, its cardinality may be incorrect. Maybe adding a `DISTINCT` clause on the main select could help.

Comment: Didn't even think about that, now my query feels ugly :/

Answer (score 2):

You can convert all those subqueries to joins. The disadvantage is that you lose readability and may produce a huge intermediate result you must get rid of then with `DISTINCT`. This can be quite costly. `NOT IN` can be converted to an anti join (outer join and then picking the not matched rows), which is another pattern that may produce an undesiredly large intermediate result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*  
FROM contact c
JOIN businesschannel bc ON bc.partner_idpartner = c.partner_idpartner
JOIN business b ON bc.idbusinesschannel IN (b.idbusinessfrom, b.idbusinessto)
                AND b.idbusiness = 5943 
LEFT JOIN businesscontact bco ON bco.contact_idcontact = c.idcontact
                              AND bco.business_idbusiness = 5943
WHERE bco.contact_idcontact IS NULL;
```

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. Removing the subqueries can theoretically be done, but I think it's impractical. The performance of the resulting query can be catastrophic. Even if you have the best indexes, the query could be really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query: I did not test

```
DECLARE @tblNotInIUdContact TABLE (  CONTACT_IDCONTACT INT)
DECLARE @tblIdBusinessFrom TABLE (   IdBusiness INT)
DECLARE @tblIdBusinessTo TABLE (     IdBusiness INT)
DECLARE @tblIdPartner TABLE (    partner_idpartner INT)

INSERT INTO @tblNotInIUdContact(CONTACT_IDCONTACT)
SELECT CONTACT_IDCONTACT FROM businesscontact WHERE BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS=5943

INSERT INTO @tblIdBusinessFrom(IdBusiness)
select idbusinessFrom from business  WHERE idbusiness=5943

INSERT INTO @tblIdBusinessTo(IdBusiness)
select idbusinessTo FROM business    WHERE idbusinessroute=5943

INSERT INTO @tblIdPartner(partner_idpartner)
SELECT partner_idpartner FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL bc
INNER JOIN @tblIdBusinessFrom bf ON bc.partner_idpartner = bf.IdBusiness

INSERT INTO @tblIdPartner(partner_idpartner)
SELECT partner_idpartner FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL bc
INNER JOIN @tblIdBusinessTo bf ON bc.partner_idpartner = bf.IdBusiness



SELECT * FROM CONTACT c
    INNER JOIN @tblIdPartner p ON c.partner_idpartner = p.partner_idpartner  
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM CONTACT c
    INNER JOIN @tblNotInIUdContact ic ON c.idcontact = ic.CONTACT_IDCONTACT
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you go

1. to replace where in : use inner join
2. to replace where not in:
   use left outer join tab2 where tab2.col is null
3. to replace union,
   I create a temporary table #mycontact with the same structure as
   CONTACT

   select * into mycontact from contact where 1=0

   insert into #mycontact
   SELECT * 
     FROM CONTACT  TA

   inner join
     (SELECT partner_idpartner FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL T0 
     inner join (  select idbusinessFrom from business  WHERE idbusiness=5943) T1 on T0.idBusinessChannel=T1.idbusinessFrom)
     left outer join (  SELECT CONTACT_IDCONTACT FROM businesscontact WHERE BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS=5943)    T2
     on T0.idcontact=T2.CONTACT_IDCONTACT
     where T2.CONTACT_IDCONTACT is null) TB on TA.partner_idpartner=TB.partner_idpartner

   insert into #mycontact

   SELECT *
     FROM CONTACT  TC
     inner join(

   ```
   (SELECT partner_idpartner FROM BUSINESSCHANNEL  T0
   INNER JOIN (  select idbusinessTo FROM business     WHERE idbusinessroute=5943) T1 on T0.idBusinessChannel=T1.idbusinessFrom)  

   left outer join ( SELECT CONTACT_IDCONTACT FROM businesscontact WHERE BUSINESS_IDBUSINESS=5943)  T2
   on T0.idcontact=T2.CONTACT_IDCONTACT
   ```

   where T2.CONTACT_IDCONTACT is null)

   ```
   TD on TC.partner_idpartner=TD.partner_idpartner
   ```

   select * from #mycontact